# Is this a legitimate equation to express the likelihood of the Bernoulli distribution, ${\mathcal {L}}(p_{\text{H}}\mid {\text{HH}})=p_{\text{H}}^2$?

Tags: maximum-likelihood

In statistics, the [likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) function (often simply called the likelihood) expresses the plausibilities of different parameter values for a given sample of data.

This equation is trying to express the likelihood of the Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p_{\text{H}}$ given the observing of two heads in two i.i.d. tosses.

${\mathcal {L}}(p_{\text{H}}\mid {\text{HH}})=p_{\text{H}}^2$

Is this a legitimate equation for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "legitimate", but you are correct - perhaps that's just as good, haha.

I'll point out why this is the case in general. Let's say we have a random variable with probability mass function $f$, which has a parameter $\theta$. We observe $x_1, ..., x_n$, which are drawn IID from this distribution. As I'll point out below, each of your $x_i$ is either $H$ or $T$, and your parameter is $p_H$.

The definition of the likelihood function is given by

$\mathcal{L}(\theta | x_1, ..., x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)$

In your case, we have the PMF

$f(H) = p_H$

$f(T) = 1 - p_H$

Meaning that for a pair of observations $HH$, we can apply the definition of the likelihood function with your PMF to get

$\mathcal{L}(p_H|HH) = f(H) f(H) = p_H p_H = p_H^2$